# Prove by induction $4^n > n^2$ for $n \geq 1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am in a critical problem with the following question. Please help me.

Prove by induction:
$$4^n > n^2 \text{ for }n >= 1$$

Base case: n = 1
$$4^1 > 1^2$$
4 > 1 which is true and for some n = k > 1 we have
$$4^k > k^2$$

Next, Induction step:
Now setting n = k+1 we get
$$4^{k+1} > (k+1)^2$$
$$4(4^k) > k^2 + 2k + 1$$
Now how will I proceed?

Comment: What have you tried so far? (base case, for a start? And where are you stuck in the induction step?)

Comment: Base case is ok, I am stuck in the induction steps.

Comment: What have you assumed for the inductive step?  Please put all of your work in the body of the question; this will help us determine exactly where to give a hint.

Comment: To get help, you may want to show your work so far (i.e., *where* are you stuck in what you have tried?)

Comment: Basic approach: First, is it true for $n = 1$ itself?  Secondly, when you increase the value of $n$ by $1$, what happens to the left side of the inequality?  How much would $n$ have to increase by in order for that *same* change to happen to the right side?  Does that ever happen when $n$ increases by $1$ (for $n \geq 1$)?

Comment: 4^(k+1) > (k+1)^2
=> 4*4^k > k^2 + 2k + 4
and then?

Comment: $4^n+4^n+4^n\gt 2n+1$ following assumption

Comment: Well, observe that $4^{k+1} = 4(4^k)$.  And if $4^k > k^2$ then $4(4^k) > 4k^2$.  And $4k^2$ is the square of what?

Comment: @Mainuddin: fyi you should show your attempt in the posting that's why you got downvotes.

Answer (score 3):

Without induction, you can show that $2^n>n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}_0$, using set theory.  It is known that $|A|<2^{|A|}$ for any set $A$, particularly, if $|A|=n$.  Then, $4^n=\left(2^n\right)^2>n^2$.

Alternatively, you can use Bernoulli's Inequality: $2^n=(1+1)^n\geq 1+n\cdot 1>n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}_0$.

Answer (score 0):

To do induction you must start with the base case so for $n=1$ you get:

$$4^1>1^2\Rightarrow4>1$$

Wich in fact is true; now suppose the relation hold for some $n=k>1$ you have that:

$$4^k>k^2$$

Now setting $n=k+1$ leads:

$$4^{k+1}=4^k\times 4=4^k+3\times4^k$$

$$(k+1)^2=k^2+2k+1$$

Combining the two expressions you have:

$$4^k+3\times4^k>k^2+2k+1$$

Wich is actually true considering that $4^n>2n+1$ for every $n>0.$

Comment: @user46944 yeah sry I know that is just the first idea that came up to my mind

Comment: How this comes? $$4^k \times 4 = 4^k + 3 \times 4^k$$

Comment: @Mainuddin This is essentially what's happening: $4a = a + 3a$

Comment: $4\times 4^k=(1+3)\times 4^k=4^k+3\times 4^k$ @Mainuddin

Comment: @ShaneT Thanks for the explanation.